# Beer Spill on my Macbook Pro Late 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, screen

I have spilled a glass of beer on my Macbook. The screen and at least some keys on the keyboard no longer work.  When I start the computer and try to log in blind, I can hear that the password is not being entered correctly so so I know that the enter key and the sound work but that's all.
My question is, is there any way I can get into this computer from another computer?  I also have a 2011 Macbook that I'm using now.  I also have a raspberry pi.

Thanks,

Ron

Comment: External monitor and keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

From macOS help:

If you have two Mac computers with FireWire or Thunderbolt ports, you can connect them so that one of them appears as an external hard disk on the other. This is called target disk mode.

Connect the two computers with a FireWire or Thunderbolt cable.

On the Mac you want to use as the disk in target disk mode, do one of the following:

- If the computer is off, start it up while holding down the T key.
- If the computer is on, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Startup Disk, then click Target Disk Mode.

When the computer has started up, a disk icon appears on the desktop of the other computer.

Transfer files by dragging them to and from the disk.

Eject the disk by dragging its icon to the Trash. While you drag, the Trash icon changes to an Eject icon.

On the Mac you used as a disk, push the power button to shut it down, then disconnect the cable.

The Apple Target Disk Mode support article is [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462).

Comment: If the above doesn't work, you can drive sending the hard drive to a recovery service. Or you can try connecting to a SATA cable yourself.

Comment: Can you add a link referencing Apples instructions for Target Disk Mode?

Comment: @JBis I can't. I searched the net for Target Disk Mode, thinking I'd get an Apple support article, but there wasn't one. This text appeared on my iMac (Mojave), when in the Finder I selected Help > macOS Help.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462

Comment: @JBis Thanks! I've added the citation to my answer.